# Codeingniter3 echo a single element of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Let's assume I have this controller function

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $clienteemail = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $cliente['nome'] = $this->model_users->lettura_dati($clienteemail);

    $data['title']='La Giumenta Bardata Dashboard'; //array per titolo e dati passati

    $this->load->view('auth/template/auth_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('auth/template/auth_nav', $cliente);
    $this->load->view('auth/clienti/auth_sidebar');
    $this->load->view('auth/clienti/client_dash');
    $this->load->view('auth/template/auth_footer');
}
```

`model_users` is a model that query the db with this function:

```
public function lettura_dati($clienteemail)
{
  $this->db->where('email', $clienteemail);
  $query = $this->db->get('user');
  if ($query) {
    $row = $query->row();
    $cliente['nome'] = $row->nome;
    return $cliente;
  } else {
    echo "errore nella ricerca del nome";
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is to use an user email from the session data to retrieve info from the db table.

so I start to retrieve just the name of the user. 
The function works, but when in the view I use `echo $nome;`

I have an error about the conversion between array and string... that's normal, I know, but if I do

```
print_r($nome);
```

my output is: `Array[0] => 'Pippo'`

I just want to output the content of the array. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've made a bit of a typo..

Your model:

```
$row = $query->row(); // Fetch the entireuser
$cliente['nome'] = $row->nome; // Set the name to a value. $cliente isn't defined yet..
return $cliente; // Return the entire $cliente array.
```

Your Controller:

You are using the above model method and assuming it is returning just the name. It is actually returning the full user.

```
$cliente['nome'] = $this->model_users->lettura_dati($clienteemail);
```

Change your model code to the following and it should work as expected.

```
public function lettura_dati($clienteemail)
{
  $this->db->where('email', $clienteemail);
  $query = $this->db->get('user');
  if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) { // Ensure we have got at least 1 row
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->nome;
  } else {
    echo "errore nella ricerca del nome";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return $row->nome;
```

instead of:

```
$cliente['nome'] = $row->nome;
return $cliente;
```

**OR**

```
$cliente_data = $this->model_users->lettura_dati($clienteemail);
$cliente['nome'] = $cliente_data['nome'];
```

instead of:

```
$cliente['nome'] = $this->model_users->lettura_dati($clienteemail);
```

Comment: and If I want to use that model function to retrieve all the row content? So I can output every values in different place of the view?